# file is encrypted or is not a database - sqlite

Tags: php, sqlite

I have some trouble to open a sqlite file

In the command line I get this:

```
#sqlite3 sms.db
SQLite version 3.6.20
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> select * from message;
Error: file is encrypted or is not a database
```

The error is not when I connect, it's when I run a query

Checking the file gets me this

```
# file sms.db
sms.db: SQLite 3.x database
```

So it should not be a version problem - like opening a sqlite2 file with sqlite3

In php I have this:

```
try 
{
    /*** connect to SQLite database ***/

    $db = new PDO("sqlite:path/sms.db");
    echo "Handle has been created ...... <br><br>";

}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo "<br><br>Database -- NOT -- loaded successfully .. ";
    die( "<br><br>Query Closed !!! $error");
}

$result = $db->query('SELECT * from message') or var_dump($db->errorInfo());
```

Gets me this (not at connect but when the query is executed)

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "HY000" [1]=> int(26) [2]=> string(38) "file is encrypted or is not a database" }
```

I use a Sql manager extension for firefox and there I can open the file without any problems(and run any query without any encryption or password). This is really strange for me. I have searched about this for the last hours but I didn't find any solution. Any help would be appreciated.

---

I have just tested on windows and I can open the database. I think the problem is related to the sqlite drivers.

On windows I have SQLite Library    3.7.7.1 
On my centos server I have SQLite Library   3.6.20

Now the question is how do I update the php sqlite extension. I can not update the entire php (it may cause errors )

Commands like yum install php-pdo, yum install php5-sqlite3, do not work

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I get this error when moving php-scripts from one hosting to another.
Most often it is bug in the mode sqlite WAL:

```
PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;
```

To solve this problem you need to disable this option in the database.
The easiest way to do this by replacing the 2 bytes in the file database \x02\x02 to \x01\x01 to the address \x12 (dec 18)
In bash, you can use commands:

```
do printf '\x01\x01' | dd of=basename.db bs=1 seek=18 count=2 conv=notrunc
```

Comment: In the end I just used java to open the database. you just have to include a jar and you do not have to modify anything on your server